# unable to update to the latest kernel

Tags: kernel, updates

I had troubles with kernels and asked a question on how to remove them

[Can I delete my most recent kernels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654014/can-i-delete-my-most-recent-kernels/654020?noredirect=1#comment940096_654020)

With the help I received I did manage to delete the offending kernels. After that I expected that new kernels would continue and I would stay up to date. In fact since then I have been stuck on the old one which works

ilan@ilan-Len-G585:~$ uname -r

3.19.0-18-generic

We are now on 3.19.0-26 and I would really like to use the latest software

dpkg -l | grep linux-image

shows that 3.19.0.25 is saved but if I try the advanced boot options of Ubuntu the highest kernel in the list is 3.19.0.18, which is the kernel it uses.

My question is how do I get back in step and start using the latest software? How do I convince the system to download (and use) 3.19.0.26?

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: Updating to version 15.10 solved the problem, i.e. it forced using the kernel of 15.10 in place of 3.19.0-18 of 15.04.